# Bash if/else error

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script to compile a program in bash and my if/else statement on line 84 is not working. I get this error:

`./build2.sh: 84: [: no: unexpected operator`

What is the problem?
http://www.pasteall.org/62904/bash

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, rather than linking elsewhere.

Comment: are you trying to pass empty string for putProgramOn?

Comment: Run your code through http://www.shellcheck.net it will catch a few issues with your script one of which might be the problem is SMA is correct about your input.

Comment: You might want to consider using `shopt -s nocasematch` before checking `$putProgramOn` as `"no"` because `"No"` and `"NO"`will cause it to fail and then set `shopt -u nocasematch` afterwards.  See, [4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

"Is not working" is very faint. However, I'll give it a try...

If enter is pressed without typing any reply, `$putProgramOn` is empty, and 
`if [ $putProgramOn == "no" ]` resolves to `if [  == "no" ]`, which is a syntax error, so you need at least to quote the reply in the conditional:

```
if [ "$putProgramOn" == "no" ]
```

See also [Bash Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

BTW: With esac you can simply have shortcuts "y" and "n" evaluated as well:

```
read -p 'Would you like to put the program on the flash drive? Awnser yes or no: ' putProgramOn

case "$putProgramOn" in
n|no)
    echo "putProgramOn=no"
    ;;
y|yes)
    echo "putProgramOn=yes"
    ;;
*)
    echo "putProgramOn=\"putProgramOn\""
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: If you're just going to test for lowercase responses you should set `shopt -s nocasematch` before and `shopt -u nocasematch` afterwards as an uppercase "N" or Y", etc. will fail. See my comment to John Roper's question.

Comment: "${putProgramOn,,}" is also possible. [https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html]